# Import variable from file in upper folder

Tags: python

In my python script  I have defined: `my_variable = ['1','2']`.

A few lines later I run a function `def func()`contained in a module. This module is contained in a Package. This package is saved in the same folder as my initial python syrypt.

The function `func()` needs *my_variable*.

As far as I know Python uses the Local/Global/Built-in rule.

However, if I run the code, I get the error

> my_variable is not defined

So, shouldn't *my_variable* be found automatically? Or do I need to import *my_variable* into the module containing `func()`?

Comment: Why not just pass it in as an argument

Comment: Just tried it, worked, thanks a lot!